# Cert shows certification chain differently on different machine

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, keystore

I was given an SSL certificate (.cer extension) by a software vendor. When I open it in my laptop, I can see

> This certificate is intended for the following purposes:
>
> - All application policies
>
> Issue To: uat.xxxxxx.sg
>
> Issue By: XXXXXX.

Under the "Certification path" tab, I can the chain, with "XXXXXX" at the top, and "uat.xxxxxx.sg" below it. The certificate status below shows:

> Certificate status:
>
> The issuer of this certificate could not be found.

I copied this certificate to a server (let's call it server XYZ), and opened it on the server, it shows:

> Windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate:
>
> Issue To: uat.xxxxxx.sg
>
> Issue By: XXXXXX.

And under the "Certificate path" tab, it only show a single "uat.xxxxxx.sg",

> Certificate status:
>
> The issuer of this certificate could not be found.

Why does it show differently on different machine?

On my laptop, I imported the certificate file into a Java keystore file. This would be my trust store. Then I ran a small Java program that I wrote myself to connect to the software vendor's server with one-way SSL, with the following parameters to specify the trust store. The program ran fine as it was able to connect successfully with the software vendor's server.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=....
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword....
```

However, when I took the program and keystore to server XYZ, and ran it, it failed "unable to find valid certification path to requested target". It seems that the certificate has become unknown on server XYZ, even though it is in my truststore.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are u certain that the certificate is in your trust-tore? You can list the certs and check this. keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks

Comment: A .cer can include the leaf certificate and also the certification chain to the root CA that has issued the certificate. In your case seems the chain is missing. In your laptop probably you have installed the issuer, then when the Operative System shows the certificate, it finds the issuer in the System trustore and shows it too. In your server probably the issuer certificate is not installed.

Comment: Yes, I am certain that it is in my trust store. I did copy the trust store file (.jks) directly from my laptop to the server XYZ. I ran your command on server XYZ and I can see the certificate "uat.xxxxxx.sg" listed. I have also ran my program with -Djavax.net.debug=all and can see my cert in the output. However, at the end of the output, I can see description "certificate_unknown".

Comment: Including the certificate in the truststore should be enough to be connect to the SSL server. But the usual configuration is include the root CA, not the leaf certificate. Could you import it into JKS? If it does not work, may be is a misconfiguration in server side

Comment: Hi pedrofb, I ran "mmc" on my laptop and can see the issuer "XXXXXX" under "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities". On server XYZ, I don't see the issuer when I ran "mmc". That probably explains why the certificate chain showed differently on my laptop and server XYZ?

Comment: Hi pedrofb, when I ran the keytool -list command on the keystore file in server XYZ, I can see both "uat.xxxxxx.sg" and  "XXXXXX". When I ran my program, I can also see "uat.xxxxxx.sg" as chain[0], and "XXXXXX" as chain[1]. When I opened the certificate of "XXXXXX", it does not have a root CA in the certificate chain.

Comment: Correction: when I ran keytool -list, I can only see "uat.xxxxxx.sg" and not the issuer "XXXXXX". Perhaps I should import the issuer into the keystore as well?

Comment: 1)Yes, that's what I said above 2) Importing only "XXXXX" in truststore is the usual configuration to trust in server. Try to import it. If it does not work, could you check the server with SSLLabs to see if there are errors on certification chain?

Comment: Hi pedrofb, I did as you suggested (import "XXXXXX" into the truststore), and now my program works! Initially I only imported "uat.xxxxxx.sg" certificate into the truststore and I didn't know that I need to do another import for the issuer certificate "XXXXXX". The program was able to run on my laptop because "XXXXXX" was already in my laptop's Windows trust store.

Comment: Note that Java does not use Windows trust store. Probably in your laptop the root CA was included in the default JVM truststore at `jre/lib/security/cacerts`. I posted a summary as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(solved in comments)

> Why does it show differently on different machine?

A `.cer` will include the leaf certificate. When the operative system shows the certificate it looks for the certification chain and the root CA in the system trust store

In your laptop probably you have installed the issuer in the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" of the System truststore. Then when the Operative System shows the certificate, it finds the issuer in the System trustore and shows it too.

In your server seems the certification chain of the issuer is not installed, then the certificate visualizer does not find it.

> It seems that the certificate has become unknown on server XYZ, even though it is in my truststore.
>   What could be the problem?

Including the root CA certificate into the JKS truststore should be enough to be connect to the SSL server. Try to import "XXXXXX" into the JKS.

Comment: `A .cer can include one or more certificates` - it is incorrect. `.cer` can contain only one certificate. Multiple certificates (say, certificate chain) are stored usually in a PKCS#7 file (`.p7b` file extension).

Comment: Well, `.cer` is used in some cases as synonymous of PEM, but think is not the usual case as you pointed. I correct the answer. Thanks